# Using stored procedures results in update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I've got a table with two columns(among others): id and created_in_variant and a stored procedure that calculates the created_in_variant value basing on the id.
I'd like to do something like this:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[alerts]
     SET [created_in_variant] = find_root [id]
```

Is there a nice way to do it?

Comment: Can you provider some details on exactly what "find_root" is doing?

Comment: @Tom H. I don't think the functionality of "find_root" is relevant here though, IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look at using a *scalar valued function* (also known as a *user defined function*) instead of a stored procedure for this type of problem.

**EDIT**: Here is some information concerning SVFs : [Click](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/user-defined-functions)

**EDIT 2**: Here is some more information from [15 Seconds](http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/000817.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Change your proc into a UDF and you basically call it exactly as you got

```
UPDATE [dbo].[alerts]
     SET [created_in_variant] = dbo.find_root([id])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are *forced* to use stored procedure to implement what you have asked, you can simply save the found root value in a variable and pass it along.
There is **no** simpler way unless you use a UDF (user-defined function) like others have mentioned.

This is one of the simplest answers when using stored procedure *because* you cannot pass stored procedure directly to the `UPDATE` statement.  There is no interpolation like in other languages like C# or Java.

```
declare @root int
-- 1) Return the root through output parameter
exec find_root @id, @root out
-- or make the sproc to return the root value
exec @root = find_root @id
UPDATE [dbo].[alerts]
     SET [created_in_variant] = @root
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the stored procedure as a scalar valued function.  Then you can use this for your update.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make the created_in_variant a computed field?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a UDF instead of a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. If you turned the stored procedure into scaler function that'd work.

If you wanted to use a stored procedure you have to call the stored procedure for each id (in a cursor) and return the value in a OUTPUT variable then do the update for each id w/ the output variable. However, It'd be much better to use a UDF.

Answer (score 0):

You could reprogram the stored procedure to a user defined function and use that.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply missing dbo., DJ answer shuold already be good. i had the same exact problem today.